# Stopping bots from registering on pay per click?

Tags: php, pay-per-click

I'm writing a pay per click function on my site. It's fairly easy to add a link on a button:

```
 http://www.mysite.com/advertLink?id=123
```

I could pick up the ID and redirect accordingly. But how do I stop Google and other bots from "clicking" on this link? I don't want the users that are clicking on the link to be charged for clicks that are generated by bots?

Also, are there other types of traffic I should consider blocking? I am considering, for example, blocking all traffic outside of my country from being registered as clicks because this site is very much only directed at my country?

**UPDATE**

The nofollow and htaccess rules are a good start. But I was hoping there was perhaps more foolproof way. I see, for example on this site: www.pricecheck.co.za, that if you click on an add, it takes you to a fancy forwarding page. I am curious as to what logic is on that page. It also looks like perhaps javascript is used somehow. See what I mean here:

```
http://www.pricecheck.co.za/offers/19453458/Apple+iPad+2+Black+64GB+9.7%22+Tablet+With+WiFi+&+3G/
```

Comment: A small based solution, although I'm not sure how well it would work, the larger bots have specific user agents, which you could detect and then prevent interaction that way

Comment: Not sure if this is the best solution, but can you use your `.htaccess` file to block crawlers from the `advertLink` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your button to an `a` link and put `rel="nofollow"` which should tell search engines not to follow the link. Alternatively you could display the link using javascript and search engines normally wont follow it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<a href="http://www.mysite.com/advertLink?id=123" rel="nofollow">link</a>');
</script>
```

and like hakan says, add rules to disallow it in your robots.txt.

You could also check the referrer in your script to make sure it was clicked on from your page.

Answer (score 0):

Nice bots will read and respect your [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html). You can write something like

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /advertLink
```